# Int Array Division Algorithm in C

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, math, date-arithmetic

I'm working on dividing two arrays of integers. For example, the number 2222222220 and the number 3124151510 are stored in an integer array, and each index is subtracted repeatedly to represent the quotient in float form. However, I couldn't get the printed result. There is nothing when I run the code. How can I fix it? My code is same as the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void
divArr(int compare1[], int compare2[])
{
    int loopIndex, supp = 0;
    int res[20] = {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };
    bool bigger = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int x = i; x < 10; x++) {
            if (i > 0 && compare1[i - 1] != 0) {
                bigger = true;
                break;
            }
            else {
                if (compare1[x] < compare2[x]) {
                    for (int y = 9; y > i; y--) {
                        compare2[y] = compare2[y - 1];
                    }
                    compare2[i] = 0;
                    bigger = false;
                    break;
                }
                else if (compare1[x] > compare2[x]) {
                    bigger = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        while (bigger == true) {
            for (int j = 9; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (compare1[j] >= compare2[j]) {
                    compare1[j] = compare1[j] - compare2[j];
                }
                else {
                    compare1[j] = compare1[j] - compare2[j] + 10;
                    compare1[j - 1] -= 1;
                }
            }
            res[i] += 1;

            for (int x = i; x < 9; x++) {
                if (i > 0 && compare1[i - 1] != 0) {
                    bigger = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    if (compare1[x] < compare2[x]) {
                        for (int y = 9; y > i; y--) {
                            compare2[y] = compare2[y - 1];
                        }
                        compare2[i] = 0;
                        bigger = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (compare1[x] > compare2[x]) {
                        bigger = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
        printf("%d\n", res[k]);
    }
}

int
main()
{

    int compare1[10] = { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0 };
    int compare2[10] = { 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 0 };
    divArr(compare1, compare2);
    return 0;
}
```

0.711304241451465 or just 0711304241451465

Comment: you are stuck in a loop, it looks like bigger is never set to flase, step through with your debugger, or add some debugging printfs

Comment: It's unclear [to me, at least] what you're trying to achieve. Adding some more explanation and/or comments to the code would help. I ran the code, and there is an infinite loop. When I run it under `gdb`, and do ctrl-c, it appears to be [mostly] at line 40: `compare1[j] = compare1[j] - compare2[j];` So, I think your code doesn't set `bigger` to `false` to end the `while (bigger == true)` loop. I'd either single step the code under `gdb` and/or add debug `printf` statements.